# if you don't use scaffolding, is ruby on rails still good for rapid development?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django

If you take out the scaffolding feature where it creates the model/controller, and CRUD pages for you, **is ruby on rails still any faster to market than say, django**?

It seems very similiar to be if you take away that step...(even though I believe django has similar auto-gen capabilities)

I am reading the starting guide on the rails site, and when it introduces the scaffolding feature, it says that many people prefer to hand code these types of areas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never seen Rails scaffold-generated view code used in a production app. The chances that it's going to create the look that you want is nearly zero. I use the generators for models and controllers all the time, as they are very useful.

To your question of frameworks:

If you know Python better, use Django.
If you know Ruby better, use Rails.

If this is a hobby site, use whichever one interests you the most.

Answer (score 2):

The default scaffolding is generally only useful as a starting point, and doesn't provide too much of a leg up on a real app. If you want something Rails-based that provides better scaffolding, check out [Hobo](http://hobocentral.net/) or [ActiveScaffold](http://activescaffold.com/) -- both provide scaffold-style functionality, but take it a lot further than Rails does by default.

As far as Rails vs. Django, they provide pretty similar functionality, though Django has built-in account management. Which one you use should be more a matter of language preference than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Scaffolding is just a demo and learning feature. It's not intended for use in real site development. It's certainly not Rails' primary strength.

Comment: so in the end its the same idea, different language that's all compared to django/python.